How to calculate velocity of air behind a propeller?
Background:
I came across this article by Gabriel Staples to calculate static and dynamic thrust of a propeller. In the derivation, it was assumed that the exit velocity is equal to the pitch speed of the propeller, a function of RPM and propeller pitch (inches). However, it was also mentioned that this assumption is far from truth in real life, so the final thrust equation derived was empirically corrected.
Question:
I want to know what will be the average airspeed behind the propeller (exit velocity), if the engine is not moving forward (static thrust). Is there a way to calculate it?
(I want to know this speed to calculate the effectiveness of control surfaces submerged in the propwash)

As engineer: calculate but do not trust results: measure them! Answers below may give you some estimates, but they assume a lot.

You want to look into hover momentum theory.
The induced velocity at a hovering rotor $v_i$ is:
$$v_i=\sqrt{\frac{T}{A}\frac{1}{2\,\rho}}$$
Where $T$ is the thrust and $A$ is the area of the disk, so $T/A$ is the disk loading.  $\rho$ is the air density.
After the rotor, the streamtube that passes through the rotor will contract and accelerate.  Eventually, it will reach a velocity of twice the velocity at the rotor.

So what you're saying is exit velocity=2*entry velocity? But then... How do we calculate this, how is entry velocity calculated? How do you get from rotor parameters to exit velocity?

Since the rotor is in hover, far above the rotor, the velocity is zero.  At the plane of the rotor, the velocity is v_i.  Far after the rotor, the velocity is 2v_i.  You calculate v_i (the velocity induced by the rotor) using the equation I gave -- which is in terms of thrust and area.

Yes, if you know the propeller dimensions and the thrust this propeller generates.
From this answer we can derive an equation which gives exit speed in relation to thrust:
$$\Delta v = \sqrt{\frac{8\cdot T}{\pi\cdot d_p^2\cdot \rho}}$$
This is only valid for the static case: Entry speed is assumed to be zero.
Nomenclature:
$\Delta v$ = exit speed in m/s
$T\;\,$  = thrust in N
$d_p\,$ = propeller diameter in m
$\rho\;\;$ = air density in kg/m³

Sorry for commenting on an old post but the two formulas don't "match" if you solve for A=πr^2.  Should 8T be 2T in the bottom formula? Thanks!!

@user9251544 If you use the prop radius, 2 is the correct constant. If you use the prop diameter (which I do here), 8 is correct.

There’s a good chance I’m doing a childish mistake here but I’ll ask again just in case…  If I replace d with 2r in your formula, shouldn’t I get the top formula? With d=2r, the denominator becomes π4r^2ρ so the fraction becomes  2T / Aρ instead of T / A2ρ given in the top formula, what am I missing? I’m asking because I tried the same numbers with both formulas and they give wildly different results. Thanks again for your time!!

@user9251544 Since there is only one formula in this answer, I guess you refer to the linked answer, which has three distinct ones and more within the text. The first two are the same, only that initial speed has been set to zero in the second. The second formula is reproduced here, solved for ∆v. If you replace d/2 by r in both, they will still be equivalent. Where is the mistake supposed to be? Don't forget that r² is d²/4, and the fraction under the root in the formula in this answer here should read 2·T / (π·r²·ρ).

Thanks for your patience and getting back to me. The two equations I'm referring to are the ones on this page only, one from you and one from Rob. We both agree that if you solve your equation with r=d/2, you get 2T / Aρ but Rob has T / 2A*ρ (his 2 is in the denominator and yours in the nominator). They should be the same, shouldn't they?

@user9251544 It helps to be precise. Now I see what you mean. Rob's induced speed is the added speed in the propeller plane whereas ∆v is the speed behind the propeller. ∆v = 2·v$_\text{i}$, as explained here

yeap it was a childish mistake, should have read everything more carefully, thanks again!!
